# How can I embed an external page on another page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I work at a real estate brokerage and we have been using the code below to embed saved property listing searches on our Wordpress site.

```
<div style="width: 800px;">
<object data="http://google.com" width="800" height="700"> 
<embed src="http://google.com" width="800" height="700" /> 
</object>
</div>
```

This worked fine for the longest time, but recently all the embedded pages aren't showing up. All I can think of is we had to update our version of wordpress to 4.8.2 and it seems they've disabled the html tags embed, object, and iframe in favor of their own [embed]. My problem is I need to be able to embed a page within another page, but wordpress will not acknowledge any html code for embedding and their own has a whitelist so it will not embed just any webpage. Any help with this would be hugely appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in the console of your web browser if you visit the page with the embeds? They may have been blocked by the owner of the page you are trying to embed, you should see errors in your console.

If it's as you suspect and your tags are being stripped out by wordpress then you should be able to overcome that with a custom shortcode. Here's a basic example

```
function propertysearch_func( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'data' => 'https://www.example.com',
            'src' => 'https://www.example.com',
        ), $atts, 'propertysearch' );
    return '<div style="width: 800px;">
<object data="' . $atts[data] . '" width="800" height="700"> 
<embed src="' . $atts[src] . '" width="800" height="700" /> 
</object>
</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'propertysearch', 'propertysearch_func' );
```

Put that in the functions.php of your child theme, or as an mu-plugin or whatever, then in wordpress you can use

```
[propertysearch data="https://objectDataURLhere.com" src="https://EmbedSRChere.com"]
```

Comment: Thank you it looks like you've helped me get to the bottom of this, in the console it gives the error:

Blocked loading mixed active content

Comment: Mixed content means some is encrypted and some isn't. So either your site, or the site you are trying to embed is not serving their content over HTTPS. If it's your site then you can fix it by getting an SSL certificate and using HTTPS instead of HTTP. If it's the other site which is still using HTTP then there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this was a conflict where our site has https and the the site embedded does not. Almost makes me regret getting our SSL certificate, but I suppose not much can be done to fix this. Just going to need to find another way to get that information on our pages. There's not much in the way of a workaround but the reason for the issue at least is solved. Thank you.